# Outer join in LINQ Problem

Tags: c#, linq, subsonic3

Id like to perform an outer join with the second join statement in this query, I keep getting weird errors! (it must be the 3rd RedBull)

```
var Objeto = from t in Table1.All()
             join su in table2.All() on t.Id equals su.Id
             join tab2 in Table1.All() on t.PId equals tab2.Id //<-I want it here
             select new
             {
                 t.Field1,
                 SN = su.Field123,
                 PTN = tab2.FieldABC
              };
```

Any help would be appreciated.

[Edit] - I neglected to say that I'm using SubSonic 3.0, the bug seems to be with SubSonic.....

Comment: You have to tell us what the "weird errors" are in order for us to be able to help you

Comment: can you provide a sample with more than one joing, where only one of them is 'outer'?

Comment: When I do this I get: " The expression of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`2[<>f__AnonymousType0`2[x,a],System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[w]]]' is not a sequence "

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Performing an outer join requires two steps:

1. Convert the join into a group join with `into`
2. Use `DefaultIfEmpty()` on the group to generate the `null` value you expect if the joined result set is empty.

You will also need to add a `null` check to your `select`.

```
var Objeto = from t in Table1.All()
             join su in table2.All() on t.Id equals su.Id
             join tab2 in Table1.All() on t.PId equals tab2.Id into gj
             from j in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new
             {
                 t.Field1,
                 SN = su.Field123,
                 PTN = (j == null ? null : j.FieldABC)
              };
```

Comment: When I do this I get: " The expression of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`2[<>f__AnonymousType0`2[x,a],System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[w]]]' is not a sequence "

Comment: What LINQ provider are you using? Are you sure it supports outer joins?

Comment: What types are returned by Table1.All() and Table2.All()? Generally they should either both be IQueryable<_> or IEnumerable<_> - it looks like they're currently mixed, which might confuse the compiler.

Comment: They both return the same type, it seems to be a SubSonic issue.

Comment: This is the proper way to do an Outer Join in LINQ, my errors where caused by SubSonic